# Only default themes are listed in Gnome Tweaks

Tags: gnome, themes, default, tweak

Linux noobie here, using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop.

I'm having issues installing custom themes (downloaded from Gnome-Look), in this case Application themes, using Gnome Tweaks. No matter what I try, all that Gnome Tweaks lists are the default themes.

I've tried creating a .themes directory in /home/ (as it didn't exist before), putting the extracted theme folders in there. I made sure the theme folders have index.theme files in them, and have gtk-3.0 compatibility (I believe reading about that being a potential issue?)

Help would be greatly appreciated, as it's becoming a massive headache for me.

UPDATE: It seems as though the issue is on the themes themselves rather than Tweaks. For one of my custom themes, Canta, instead of directly containing all the theme data, it had a subfolder Canta-compact, which contains the data. I moved that up into the .themes folder and deleted Canta, and now Canta-compact shows up in the list.

However, I have another theme, Magenta, which still doesn't show up. I wonder if it's because it doesn't have a gtk-3.0 folder? (all it contains is gtk-2.0, gtk-3.18, gtk-3.20, assets, and index.theme).

Comment: Is it happening for one theme or several themes ? There might be others folder in the folder of your theme that you need to put in .themes

Comment: I updated my question, after moving things around a bit (detailed in the update)

Comment: The Magenta theme just doesn't seems to work. However Magenta GTK will https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1310449/

Comment: Is there a reason it's preferred over a hidden directory in /home/? (I've gone and done that though).

Comment: @netugi Both folders should work, as I see, so either `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes`, no difference, I just stick with the latter one which was default in earlier versions, `~/.themes` has been introduced later, I didnt even noticed that.